# How to set height to 100% of element with position fixed depending on its wrapper height

Tags: height, fixed, sidebar

Here is the Fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qxksjrca/)

```
.homeFirstSection {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
}
.home_left_bar {
float: left;
background: #f67777;
width: 4%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 5;
position: fixed;
 }
```

How I can set the height of fixed part to height of its wrap?

Answer (score 0):

Found a very simple solution only setting the css height to inherit.Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxksjrca/1/) and Code

```
.homeFirstSection {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}
.home_left_bar {
float: left;
background: #f67777;
width: 4%;
height: inherit;
z-index: 5;
position: fixed;
}
```